# How to draw and shade dependent sets with legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

Suppose `$x$` and `$z$` are variables in interval `$[0,1]^2$`. How is it possible to draw the following sets and shade them and provide legend?

```
$c1 \quad if 0<x<1/13*(5-2sqrt(3)),0<z<1/2(2x+x^2)+1/2sqrt(4x^3+x^4)$
$c2 \quad if 0<x<1/13*(5-2sqrt(3)),1/2(2x+x^2)+1/2sqrt(4x^3+x^4)<z<2x$
```

Comment: You already receive answers to the very similar questions, so we expect that you now should be able to write some code on basis on received answer. BTW, so far you not accept any of received answers. Are no one of them fulfil your expectation?

Comment: You are right. I asked a similar question but here, bounds on one variable depend on another variable and based on the suggestion of others, I asked a new question.

Comment: And what you try so far?  DO you learn anything from received answers? This site is not a service to `we-do-instead-of-you` ...

Comment: @Zarko I have not much  experiences and I have not used "pgfplots" before. That is why it is vague for me and I ask questions.

Comment: You can stick with tikz and for starting point use received answers. BTW, as I see, you still not accepted any of received answer ...

Comment: Solutions are good but I don't know how to add a case when bounds on one variable depend on the other variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117903/discussion-between-katatonia-and-zarko).

Comment: Not today. Today i holiday.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic version. Of course one add keys that make things simpler. Basically you need to add two plots for the upper and lower bound and then shade the area between then. (`forget plot` just means that the auxiliary plots do not get mentioned in the legend.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm,compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,no marks,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
    xtick distance=0.25,ytick distance=0.25]
  \begin{scope}[domain=0:{(5-2*sqrt(3))/13}]
   \addplot[forget plot,name path=c1a] {0};
   \addplot[forget plot,name path=c1b] {(2*x+x^2)/2+sqrt(4*x^3+x^4)/2};
   \addplot fill between[of=c1a and c1b];
   \addlegendentry{$c_1$}
   \addplot[forget plot,name path=c2a] {(2*x+x^2)/2+sqrt(4*x^3+x^4)/2};
   \addplot[forget plot,name path=c2b] {2*x};
   \addplot fill between[of=c2a and c2b];     
   \addlegendentry{$c_2$}
  \end{scope} 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much